# If $\langle g \rangle$ is the only subgroup of order $p$, what's the order of elements $xg$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, divisibility

Somewhat getting distracted from an exercise, I noticed that if a group $G$ has only one subgroup of order $p$ where $p$ is a prime (so our subgroup is wlog generated by $g$), any conjugation $$xgx^{-1}$$
must have order p as well, i.e. be representable as $g^k$ for $1\leq k < p$.

**Question: Is there any simple criterion for the order of $xg$?**

### My observations

By induction, we can prove

*Lemma* Let $g, x\in G$ with $xg=g^kx$ with $1<k$. Then $x^ng = g^{k^n}x^n$, and furthermore,$$
  (xg)^l = g^{k\left(k^l-1\right)/{(k-1)}} x^l
$$

Now, if we demand $1<k<p$, we can note that \begin{align}
  e=g^{[\cdots]} &\iff p \vert k \frac{k^l-1}{k-1} \\
  &\iff p \vert k \:\vee\: p\vert \frac{k^l-1}{k-1} \\
  &\iff p(k-1)\vert k^l-1 \\
  &\iff p \vert k^l-1 \:\wedge\: (k-1)\vert k^l-1 \\
  &\iff p \vert k^l-1 \iff k^l \equiv 1 \mod p \\
  &\iff l \vert p-1
\end{align}
Where we used properties like $p$ being prime and $p$ and $k-1$ being coprime.

We get an immediate corollary of that:

*Observation* If $l\vert p-1$ and $\operatorname{ord}x\vert l$, we have $(xg)^l=e$, i.e. $\operatorname{ord} (xg) \mid l$.

Is there any way to strengthen this assertion? Assuming the best case scenario, can we get an explicit expression for the order of $xg$?

### Proof of the commutation rule

First we'll prove $x^ng = g^{k^n}x^n$.  The case $n=1$ is clear, so assume it holds for $n$. We have $$
x^{n+1}g = xx^ng = xg^{k^n}x^n = g^{k\cdot(k^n)}xx^n = g^{k^{n+1}}x^{n+1}.
$$
Similarly, assume $(xg)^l = g^{k\left(k^l-1\right)/{(k-1)}} x^l$ (the base case $l=1$ is clear again).  We have $$
  (xg)^{l+1} = g^{k\left(k^l-1\right)/{(k-1)}} x^{l+1} g\\
  = g^{k\left(k^l-1\right)/{(k-1)}} g^{k^{l+1}} x^{l+1}\\
  = g^{k\left(k^l-1\right)/{(k-1)}} g^{k\left(k^{l+1}-k^l\right)/{(k-1)}} x^{l+1}\\
  = g^{k\left(k^{l+1}-1\right)/{(k-1)}} x^{l+1}.
$$

Comment: I don't see how $x^ng=g^{k^n}x$ follows.  Can you show me how it holds at $n=2$?

Comment: @Randall $x^2g = xxg = xg^kx = g^kxg^{k-1}x = \ldots = g^{k\cdot k}x^2 = g^{k^2}x^2$
…oh, I see what you wanted to point out, I forgot the power on $x$. But that was a typo which is unrelated to the argument.

Comment: @Randall Alright, I fixed this in an edit. Furthermore, I made an off-by-one error by assuming an $l+1$ instead of an $l$ exponent.

Comment: You want to ask for $o(xg)$ in terms of $o(x)$ and $o(g)$, am I right? (In $D_{2p}\times H$ where $|H|$ is coprime to $2p$, the order of element $xg$ can be $2$ or $lcm(o(x),o(g))$ of $2.lcm(o(x),o(g))$; four possibilities indeed occur. So I didn't get what you expect in $o(xg)$? )

Comment: @Beginner Well that appears to be a counterexample. Would you mind adding that as an answer?